# Web scraping - Get keys from website

Tags: python, json, web-scraping

I've download all the files from the following website (which represents Bus routes of São Paulo - Brazil):
http://www.cruzalinhas.com/linha.json?key=12967
and was wondering if there is a more ellegant way of doing it.

Basically what I've done is a loop for all the values between 00000 and 99999, substituting ##### for this number
http://www.cruzalinhas.com/linha.json?key=#####
checking whether the website exists and, if does, downloading it.

Is there a way of knowing before all the keys in order to make this job more efficient?

I have all the files, but this is a very usual problem and i was wondering if there is a shortcut to solve it.

Comment: Are these listed somewhere else? Is this perhaps the bus number for example? In this case you could build a list of all existing bus numbers and query their routes. Or you ask the website owner to implement a query that lists all keys :)

Comment: The numbers are probably associated with the bus number, though I don't actually know how. And the website owner would probably pass the entire key list (he made the whole database available some time ago - but the link is broken). I was just wondering if there was a way to get the full list directly through the website. Many times I find myself downloading files from websites that make the data available for scraping but this kind obstacles make the process much less efficient (and less elegant).

Comment: You can always make this list of valid keys yourself. First time query all keys and remember the ones that were working. Next time you only have to query those which actually exist. But this is only working if the keys are not changing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm the creator of [Cruzalinhas](http://www.cruzalinhas.com), and apologize in advance for not having (yet) translated the site from Portuguese to English, which would otherwise would make these matters clearer (and this answer shorter).

As you may have noticed, the data shows transportation routes for buses, subways and trains in São Paulo in a way that makes it easier to find their connections to plan routes with connections (Google Maps and others make it automatically, sometimes missing routes that could be found with more interactive search).

It uses [geohashes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geohash) for "cheap" proximity search between routes), and crawls its data from the São Paulo Transportation Company (SPTrans).

**To answer your first question**: those IDs are the ones from the original site. However, they are not really much stable (I've seen they removing an old ID and replacing a new one just because a line changed routes), so Cruzalinhas does a full crawl every now and then and updates the entire database (I'd replace it completely, but Google App Engine makes it a bit harder than usual).

The good news: the site is open-sourced (http://github.com/chesterbr/cruzalinhas) under an MIT license. Documentation is also still in Portuguese, but you will be mostly interested in [`sptscraper`](https://github.com/chesterbr/cruzalinhas/blob/master/src/sptscraper/sptscraper.py), the command-line crawler.

**The most efficient way to get the data** is to do a `sptscraper.py download`, then `sptscraper.py parse`, then `sptscraper.py dump` and import from there. There are more options, and here is a quick translation of its help screen:

> ```
> Downloads and parses data from public transportation routes from the SPTrans
> website.
>
> It parses HTML files and stores the result in the linhas.sqlite file, which
> can be used in other applications, converted to JSON or used to update
> cruzalinhas itself.
>
> Commands:
> info          Shows the number of pending updates
> download [id] Downloads HTML files from SPTrans (all or starting with id)
> resume        Continues the download from the last line saved.
> parse         Reads downloaded HTMLs and (soft) inserts/updates/deletes in
>               the database.
> list          Outputs a JSON with the route IDs from the database.
> dump [id]     Outputs a JSON with all routes in the database (or just one)
> hashes        Prints a JSON with the geohashes for each line (mapping to
>               the routes that cross the hash)
> upload        Uploads the pending changes in the database to cruzalinhas.
> ```

Keep in mind that this data is **not taken with SPTrans consent**, even though this is public information and **they are [legally obliged](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freedom_of_information_laws_by_country#Brazil) to do so**. The site and the scraper were created as an act of protest against that, before the specific freedom of digital information law passed (even though there was already previous legislation regulating the availability of public service information, so no illegal act was conducted in this, or will be if you use it responsibily).

For that reason (and due to the fact that the back end is a bit... "challenged"), the scaraper is very careful in throttling the requests, in order to avoid overloading their servers. It makes the crawling span towards several hours, but you don't want to overload the service (which may force them into blocking you, or even changing the site to make crawling harder).

I'll eventually do a full rewrite of that code (was likely my first Python/App Engine code, written a few years ago, and a quick hack focused on exposing how useful this public data can be outside the confines of SPTrans' website). It will have a saner crawling process, should make the latest data available for download on a single click, and likely make a full lines list available on the API.

For now, if you just want the last crawling (which I did a month or two ago), just contact me and I'll be happy to send you the sqlite/JSON files.

Comment: (of course, if you want a generic answer for the problem, I'd say that, assuming the site doesn't *change* the information and always adds new IDs, the best I could imagine would be to store tha last crawled ID and monitor the next IDs to see if new ones appear)